# Select with multiple parameters returns mysql syntax error

Tags: c#, mysql, syntax, datagrid

So, i'm workind with this dataGrid. It has various filter options. Which one calls a method that selects from database the registers that matches the filter and fill the dataGrid with it. 
In one of them I have to select products by filtering them with the user ID, name of the product, and status (bought or wishlist).

The code follows:

```
SELECT product_name,
  product_type,
  product_status,
  product_store,
  product_price
FROM tbl_product
WHERE user_id    = user.Id ,
  product_status = status
AND product_name LIKE 'productName%';
```

Visual Studio crashes when i try to use this particular code with the "wrong syntax for mysql" error. It's probably a goofy error i'm not seeing, but I'm grateful if anyone could respond what's wrong.

Comment: Did you try to run this query in MySQL directly?

Comment: where user_id = user.Id **and** product_status = status

Comment: What is _status_, what is _user.id_. If they are variables of your C# code then you are making a lot of confusion about what is a parameter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have use "and" in place of a comma

```
SELECT product_name,
  product_type,
  product_status,
  product_store,
  product_price 
FROM tbl_product 
WHERE user_id = user.Id 
 AND product_status = status 
 AND product_name LIKE 'productName%';
```

Comment: Thanks, it helped a lot. A goofy error. ;D